# Is there a way to create a variable that relies on a complex set of (ping pong) rules, without using a loop?

Tags: r, loops

I'm working on a ping pong data project. I have a big dataset that includes recorded data from each serve of a ping pong game, with a variable indicating who won which point, and a variable indicating who began the game with the serve - but no variable indicating who is serving any given point. The rules (or at least, our house rules) of ping pong allow me to deduce this final variable - the serve switches off every five serves, and once a player gets to game point the other player takes over serve, until they get to game point. Take for example the following match, in which nobody breaks serve until 20-20, at which point player 1 wins two consecutive points to win the match 22-20 (first to 21, win by 2).

```
WonServe <- "Player1"
Serve <- seq_len(42)
MatchNum <- rep(1, 42)
Player1Points <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
Player2Points <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
ServingPlayer <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,NA,NA)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Serve, Player1Points, Player2Points, ServingPlayer, MatchNum))
```

Now, I know who was serving for the first 40 serves, but after that things get tricky. Player 1 serves first at 20-20, since he won the serve originally (it now switches back to him). However, once he takes the lead at 21-20, player 2 takes over the serve. I'm looking to model this rule in my data to find out who was serving for each serve past serve 40. Using a loop, this could look like this:

```
for(i in 41:length(df$ServingPlayer)) {

  if(i == 41) {

    if(WonServe == "Player1") {df$ServingPlayer <- 1} else if(WonServe == "Player2") {df$ServingPlayer <- 0}

  } else if(i > 41) {

    if(cumsum(df$Player1Points[i]) > cumsum(df$Player2Points[i])) {

      df$ServingPlayer[i] <- 0

    } else if(cumsum(df$Player1Points[i]) < cumsum(df$Player2Points[i])) {

      df$ServingPlayer[i] <- 1

    } else if(cumsum(df$Player1Points[i]) == cumsum(df$Player2Points[i])) {

      df$ServingPlayer[i] <- df$ServingPlayer[i-1]

    }

  }

}
```

My problem with this is that we have a huge dataset that includes hundreds of games (don't judge). If I were to use this on the entire dataset, I (think I) would have to create a loop within a loop, applying this loop to every value of `df$MatchNum` within the dataset - and that would get really slow.

- In general, is there a way to apply this sort of logic without using loops at all?
- If not, is there at least a way to apply this single loop to a long dataset that includes many different matches without using a huge loop?

Comment: Why are we trying to avoid loops here? I'm not sure I understand the motivation. What is the desired output for your sample input? It would be nice to have a dataset with multiple matches if that's what the real problem is. That way possible solutions can be tested.

Comment: "since he won the serve originally"? Does that mean the player who "won the first point" is the one who serves at 20-20?

Comment: In general:  For problems with a "state" (who served last) and a sequence of "updates" (who is winning), you can avoid explicit use of for loops by using `Reduce`. Usually takes some cleverness, though

Answer (score 0):

You can make a longer than needed serve indicator vector and then extract only the length needed:

```
 c(rep( rep(1:0, each=5), 4), rep(Player1Points[1]:Player2Points[1], times=20) )[ 1:length(Player1Points)]
#-------
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
[33] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```